# Weird that-clause from GRE

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, clauses, exam-questions, subordinate-clauses

> Nylenna's study showed that errors in scientific manuscripts submitted
>   for publication often escape reviewer's notice results that were not
>   _______: when Godlee conducted a study of the same phenomenon, her findings were similar.
>
> A. credible
>   B. unwelcome
>   C. anomalous
>   D. quantifiable
>   E. consequential

I know the answer is *C. anomalous*, but cannot understand why. To make my question clearer, let's extract a complete sentence from it:

> Nylenna's study showed that errors in scientific manuscripts submitted
>   for publication often escape reviewer's notice results **that were not
>   anomalous**.

My question is: what is anomalous?

From the context, it seems "Nylenna's study" is anomalous, since the same result is reproduced by Godlee. However, it should be "that *was* not anomalous" in this case.

Also, what is "notice results"? Is it a phrase or just two separate words?

Comment: There should be a comma after *notice*: *results that were not anomalous* is a supplemental comment on the main clause. The results reported in Nylenna's study (and summarized in the main clause) were not *anomalous* with the results reported in other studies, such as Godlee's.

Comment: @StoneyB wow that makes perfect sense! This tiny typo is really confusing. Since this comment has solved my question, I think you should make it answer, so that I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to parse that monster of a sentence a few times before I understood it.

Presumably there should have been a comma after “notice”.  The result***s*** of Nylenna’s study **were** not anomalous because they are similar to Godlee’s finding***s***.